# React-native expo project GoogleLogin giving missing support for the following URL Schemes

Tags: react-native, expo

Hi i have done the configuration for my react native expo project. And same is working in Andorid emulator, But with iOS emulator its giving error stating "Exception: Your app is missing support for the following URL schemes:"

i have added the `reservedClientId` in app.json file to.

also i am proving the `androidClientId`, and `iosClientId` as key instead of storing them inside app.json.

Below is my app.json file.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "xyz",
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "host.exp.exponent",
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "config": {
        "reservedClientId": "com.googleusercontent.apps.givenId"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue!

Comment: Any solution? Please share

Comment: @user3819810 Nope. Couldnt found. I think this is a break in the library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make an Expo GoogleSignIn request in iOS you need to set an extra parameter

> behavior: 'web'

According to documentation it is default set but this issue only comes when you update to sdk 31.0.0

All you need to make a request like this:

```
  const result = await Google.logInAsync({
    androidClientId: 'Your Client ID',
    iosClientId: 'Your Client ID',
    scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
    behavior: 'web',
  });

  if (result.type === 'success') {
    console.log (result.user)
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Struggled with this thing like hell. Thanks again.